# Unable to access SID express-session

Tags: reactjs, express, session, express-session

I am trying to store userId in session, but for some reason I am unable to access the session in other routes. We want to store the userId in session so that i can send userId over every network call

Here is the react code

```
import axios from "axios";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  async function storeClick() {
    try {
      console.log("storeClick");
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/store/randomUserId", {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      const data = res.data;
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  async function retrieve() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/retrieve", {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      const data = res.data;
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  async function deleteClick() {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/delete", {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      });
      const data = res.data;
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={storeClick}>Store</button>
      <button onClick={retrieve}>Retrieve</button>
      <button onClick={deleteClick}>Delete</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Express code

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: ["http://127.0.0.1:5173"],
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "my-secret-key",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
      secure: false,
    },
  })
);

app.get("/store/:id", (req, res) => {
  req.session.userId = req.params.id;
  console.log(req.session);
  req.session.save();
  res.send({ message: "Session data stored" });
});

app.get("/retrieve", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.session, req.cookies);
  const userId = req.session.userId;
  if (userId) {
    res.send({ userId });
  } else {
    res.status(404).send({ message: "Session data not found" });
  }
});

app.get("/delete", (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy();
  res.send({ message: "Session data deleted" });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

in the /store endpoint when i log the req.session i can see that the session object have userId but i can't see it /retrieve endpoint

here is the express-session debug log

```
  express-session no SID sent, generating session +0ms
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-10-08T06:24:43.622Z,
    originalMaxAge: 604800000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  },
  userId: 'randomUserId'
}
  express-session saving veIbEj0_Cp_LdXgjz1DmdA8mdGYn3_k0 +3ms
  express-session set-cookie connect.sid=s%3AveIbEj0_Cp_LdXgjz1DmdA8mdGYn3_k0.wvOjqXl%2F98vEl%2B8Ml6fPvUsnKWdJ7OoJPoXi9Kx3x34; Path=/; Expires=Sun, 08 Oct 2023 06:24:43 GMT; HttpOnly +3ms
GET /store/randomUserId 200 7.609 ms - 33
  express-session no SID sent, generating session +3s
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2023-10-08T06:24:46.209Z,
    originalMaxAge: 604800000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  }
} [Object: null prototype] {}
GET /retrieve 404 1.928 ms - 36
```